# Ruby hashing problems

Tags: ruby

I have a large .txt file, which contains some data, mapping crashing inputs to programs to their crash sites. The data is formatted as 
 , and each line is another crash.
I tried to run the ruby script below to automatically sort them, but it gave no output. Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

```
# !/usr/bin/ruby                                                                                                                             

fn = ARGV[0]

$result = Hash.new([])

File.open(fn, "r") do |f|
  f.readlines do |l|
    ar = l.split
    puts(ar)
    $result[ar[1]].push[ar[0]]
  end
end

$result.each do |k, v|
  puts(k)
  puts(v)
end
```

Comment: show us an example of the contents of `fn`.

Comment: and how you call the script from cli

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$result = Hash.new([])` doesn't do what you want/think it does.

It will return the *same* array when you request any non-existent key for the hash, and also it doesn't assign any array for subsequent requests for the same key.

Instead you can use the block version of `Hash.new`:

```
result = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

The version of `Hash.new` with a default value is more useful for avoiding the need for `nil` checks when you're using a hash to maintain some counts e.g.

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
counts['foo'] += 1
```